# Compile error while initializing HttpRequest headers

Tags: c#, http-headers, reddit

I am trying to initialize an `HttpClient` based on some Python code.

I am getting a compiler error when trying to create a custom header for the 'data' header in the python code:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string?>

Same for a custom header for the "headers" header:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string?>

C# code

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"grant_type", "password" },
    {"username", Username },
    {"password", Password }
};
tokenApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("data", data); Compiler Error: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string?>

KeyValuePair<string, string> headers = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("User-Agent", "Post analysis for neural network text generation.");
tokenApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("headers", headers); // Compile Error: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string?>'
```

Python code

```
data = {
    'grant_type': 'password',
        'username': '<USERNAME>',
        'password': '<PASSWORD>'}

headers = { 'User-Agent': 'MyBot/0.0.1'}

res = requests.post('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token',
        auth=auth, data=data, headers=headers)
```

How can I Initialize it so it would act like the Python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.add?view=net-5.0

The Add method signature accepts `(string, string)` or `(string, IEnumerable<string>)`.

Looks like you'll have to loop through the dictionary and call Add per dictionary item.

You can also create some convenient extension methods, for example:

```
public static class MyHttpExtensions 
{
    public static void Add(this HttpHeaders header, IDictionary<string, string> dictTable) 
    {
        foreach (var item in dictTable) 
        {
            header.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
}
```